# Gulpfile Optimizations

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp.js

I'm looking for some advice in how well this gulp file is written out and any suggestions on improving it. Any insight is appreciated

```
/* ================================================================
   Plugins
   ================================================================ */

// Base plugins
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      gutil = require('gulp-util');

// Helper plugins
const gsize = require('gulp-size'),
      rename = require('gulp-rename'),
      notify = require("gulp-notify"),
      plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
      sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// SASS/CSS plugins
const sass = require('gulp-sass'),
      cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
      autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

// JS plugins
const concat = require('gulp-concat'),
      babel = require('gulp-babel'),
      jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
      uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// Imagemin
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

// Browsersync
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
      reload = browserSync.reload;

// Nunjucks templating
const nunjucksRender = require('gulp-nunjucks-render');





/* ================================================================
   Configs and Variables
   ================================================================ */

// Path Variables
const basePath = 'assets/',

      distPath = 'dist/',
      srcPath = 'src/',

      srcCssPath = srcPath + 'css/',
      cssPath = distPath + 'css/',
      sassPath = srcPath + 'scss/',

      jsSrcPath = srcPath + 'js/',
      jsDestPath = distPath + 'js/min/',

      srcImagesPath = srcPath + 'images/',
      distImagesPath = distPath + 'images/';


// Error Handling
var onError = function (err) {
    this.emit('end');
};

// Date Variable
var date = new Date();

const s = gsize();

// Success Message
var notifyGeneric = {
    title: function () {
        return '<%= file.relative %> - ' + s.prettySize;
    },
    onLast: true,
    subtitle: "Successfully Compiled",
    message: "@ Time: <%= options.hour %>:<%= options.minute %>:<%= options.second %> ",
    templateOptions: {
        hour: date.getHours(),
        minute: date.getMinutes(),
        second: date.getSeconds()
    }
};





/* ================================================================
   Base Tasks
   ================================================================ */

// SASS - Sourcemap and compile
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(sassPath + '*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass().on('error', notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>")))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(srcCssPath))
});


// Main CSS - Autoprefix, minify, and rename
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
    const s = gsize();

    return gulp.src(srcCssPath + 'main.css')
        .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 6 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(s)
        .pipe(gsize())
        .pipe(notify(notifyGeneric))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssPath))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});


// Admin CSS - Autoprefix, minify, and rename
gulp.task('build-admin-css', function() {
    const s = gsize();

    return gulp.src(srcCssPath + 'admin.css')
        .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
        .pipe(notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>"))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssPath))
        .pipe(s)
        .pipe(gsize())
        .pipe(notify(notifyGeneric))
});


// JS - Concatenate, babel, minify, and rename
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    const s = gsize();

    return gulp.src(['src/js/plugins.js', 'src/js/functions.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: onError }))
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(babel({ compact:false }))
        .on('error', notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
        .pipe(s)
        .pipe(gsize())
        .pipe(notify(notifyGeneric))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});


// Images - minification
gulp.task('images', function() {
    const s = gsize();

    return gulp.src('src/images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(s)
        .pipe(gsize())
        .pipe(notify(notifyGeneric))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
});


// HTML - Templating
gulp.task('nunjucks', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/templates/**/*.html')
    .pipe(nunjucksRender({
        path: ['src/templates']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/templates'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});





/* ================================================================
   Run Tasks
   ================================================================ */


// Base Watch Function
var mainWatch = function () {
    gulp.watch(sassPath + '**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(srcCssPath + 'main.css', ['build-css']);
    gulp.watch(jsSrcPath + '*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(srcImagesPath + '*', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(["src/templates/**/*.html"], ['nunjucks']);
    gulp.watch(["src/templates/pages/*.html"], ['nunjucks']);
};


// Browser Sync and Watch
gulp.task('templates', ['sass', 'build-css', 'scripts', 'images', 'nunjucks'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir:["./dist","./dist/templates"]
            //directory:true
        },
        files: "dist/css/main.min.css"
    });

    mainWatch();

    gulp.watch("dist/**/*.html").on('change', reload);
}); 


// Compile only Task (No browsersync)
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'build-css', 'scripts', 'images', 'nunjucks'], function(){
    mainWatch();
});


// Admin Style Task
gulp.task('admin-style', ['build-admin-css'], function(){
    gulp.watch(srcCssPath + 'admin.css', ['build-css']);
});
```